# From where is "Niranjano nirakara, eko devo Maheswara" mantra taken from?

Tags: mantras, identification-request

> Niranjano nirakara, eko devo Maheswara

From where is this mantra taken?

It seems to be related to the mahamritunjaya Mantra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "निरंजनो निराकार एको देवो महेश्वरः (Niranjano nirakara, eko devo Maheswara)" comes from an ancient Sanskrit tantric text named **Shiva Swarodaya**. This is found in 6th shloka of the text which contains total 395 shlokas:

> देव्युवाच

> तत्वमेव परं मूलं निश्चितं तत्त्ववादिभिः।

> तत्त्वस्वरूपं किं देव तत्त्वमेव प्रकाशय।।5।।

> Devi said:

> The tattwas (elements) are the primal cause as ascertained
> by the exponents of the tattwas. O Lord, what is the
> nature of those elements? Kindly reveal that to me.

> ईश्वर उवाच

> **[निरंजनो निराकार एको देवो महेश्वरः](https://archive.org/details/swara-yoga/page/n135)**।

> तस्मादाकाशमुत्पन्नमाकाशाद्वायुसंभवः।।6।।

> Ishwara said:

> **There is only one birthless and formless supreme
> existence** from which manifests akasha (ether element),
> and from akasha comes vayu (air element) only when he manifests

The text can be found on [Archive](https://archive.org/details/swara-yoga/) with name **Swara Yoga** with commentary and translation by Satyananda Saraswati and on [wikibooks](https://hi.wikibooks.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AF) with Hindi translation

Comment: Is mrityu mukhan ghatam pranam, bala dakrshya rakshate taken from the above as well?